# What does error code mean "ioerror; Offending Command:image mask ]%%

Tags: printer, code

meaning of printer error code:"ioerror; Offending Command:image mask ]%%

Comment: Welcome! We'd need a lot more information to help. What printer, where is the error appearing, under what circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

#### ioerror; Offending Command:image mask ]%%

That is a postscript error code.

`imagemask` (associated with 1-bit image bitmap graphics and bitmap fonts) indicates a problem with some bitmap data in your postscript file.

> **Troubleshoot PostScript errors**
>
> You can receive a PostScript error when sending a file to a PostScript
>   interpreter (for example, a printer, Acrobat Distiller). A PostScript
>   error occurs when the PostScript interpreter can't read the file's
>   PostScript code. An error can also occur if the file's PostScript code
>   exceeds one or more of the limits in the PostScript page description
>   language. If your PostScript interpreter appears to process data but
>   then stops, a PostScript error could have occurred.
>
> A PostScript error message includes a PostScript error type, which
>   defines the type of error it is. It also includes an offending
>   command, which usually indicates the specific part of the PostScript
>   code that the interpreter couldn't read. The offending command usually
>   indicates the command that caused the problem. Some PostScript errors
>   point you right to the cause of the problem, and some get you looking
>   in the right direction.
>
> Example of a PostScript error:
>
> ```
> %%[Error: ; OffendingCommand: ]%%
> ```
>
> For example, the PostScript error `%%[Error: dictfull;
>   OffendingCommand: def ]%%` contains the PostScript error type
>   `"dictfull"` and the offending command `"def."`  The error type indicates
>   that the dictionary contains the maximum number of entries. The
>   offending command is the last command the PostScript interpreter tried
>   to process, "def," which defines a new word in the dictionary.
>
> **Use the PostScript error message to start troubleshooting**
>
> After you identify a specific PostScript error message, you can begin
>   troubleshooting the cause. To begin troubleshooting, locate the error
>   type and offending command in the "PostScript Error Types" and the
>   "PostScript Offending Commands" parts of this document. You can then
>   try to repair the problem.
>
> For example, you could receive the PostScript error, "%%[Error:
>   limitcheck; OffendingCommand: image ]%%." Your first step is to locate
>   "limitcheck" in the "PostScript Error Types" section. The "PostScript
>   Error Types" section lists "limitcheck" under the heading "Exceeds
>   printer's memory or PostScript language limit." The "PostScript
>   Offending Command" lists "image" under the heading that indicates a
>   problem with bitmap data. So, you have bitmap data that exceeds the
>   printer's memory or PostScript language limit. The likeliest source of
>   bitmap data is a graphic in your file. You can then check graphics in
>   your file to see if one or more is causing the problem. If you find a
>   likely culprit, you can delete the graphic, reimport it, save it in
>   different format, or simplify it (for example, reduce its dpi). You
>   can also try printing the file to a printer with more memory.
>
> Some PostScript errors don't help you determine a likely cause. For
>   example, you could receive the PostScript error `"%%[Error: undefined;
>   OffendingCommand: ]%%."` The "PostScript Error Types" section lists
>   "undefined" under the "Errors that indicate unintelligible PostScript
>   code" heading. The "PostScript Offending Command" section lists ""
>   under the heading that indicates a problem with any element or file.
>   In this case, your file contains PostScript code the PostScript
>   interpreter can't recognize. See the "Troubleshooting Possible Causes
>   for the PostScript Error" section to continue troubleshooting.

Source [Troubleshoot PostScript errors](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/troubleshoot-postscript-errors.html)